# How to use the dd command to copy an .img file to an SD card?

Tags: command-line, permissions, partitioning, sd-card, dd

I've been trying to use the dd command to send an .img file of mine to a partition on my SD card. The command is:

```
dd if=/dev/sda6/media/david/desktop/stellar-unbrick.img of=/dev/sdb1
```

Unfortunately, all I get is:

> no such file or directory.

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried entering `sudo -i` beforehand and running as su.

Comment: do ls -al /dev/sda6/media/david/desktop

If you don't see the file stellar-unbrick.img listed in the output you have the path wrong somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without the `/dev/sda6` - that's a block device and not a directory, which is presumably mounted at `/media/david/desktop/`.